# springboot web lost important function on Heroku, but work well in localhost

Tags: java, heroku, thymeleaf

on my localhost, my web works fine like this:
[view run on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaTEY.png)

the controller can bind the List of currencies to the select box normally.
But when I deploy to Heroku, it looks like the controller never finds the right list to bind to thymeleaf. So the selection boxes are left blank:
[view run on heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw5ok.png)

here is my controller:

```java
@Autowired MoneyConverter moneyConverter;
@GetMapping("/")
  public String renderForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("moneyConvertRequest", new MoneyConvertRequest());
    List<CurrencyRate> currencies = moneyConverter.mapCurrencyRates();
    model.addAttribute("currencies", currencies);  
    return "form";
  }
```

and in the Service, my program reads files from a JSON and a CSV to parse data to a hashmap that link to Currency Data object like this:

```java
private JsonNode masterNode;
private HashMap<String, CurrencyRate> mapCurrencyRates;

public MoneyConverter() {
    loadExchangeRateFromJSON();
    loadCurrencyCodeFromCSV();
  }

private void loadExchangeRateFromJSON() {
    try {
      File file = new ClassPathResource("static/exchange_rate.json").getFile();
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      masterNode = objectMapper.readTree(bufferedReader);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public void loadCurrencyCodeFromCSV() {
    mapCurrencyRates = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      File file = new ClassPathResource("static/currency.csv").getFile();
      CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper(); 
      CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader(); 
      ObjectReader oReader = mapper.readerFor(CurrencyRate.class).with(schema); 
      Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
      MappingIterator<CurrencyRate> mi = oReader.readValues(reader); 

      while (mi.hasNext()) {
        CurrencyRate currencyRate = mi.next();
        String currencyCode = currencyRate.getCode();
        if (mapCurrencyRates.get(currencyCode) == null) { 
          float rate = getExchangeRate(currencyCode);  JSON
          if (rate > 0.0f) { 
            currencyRate.setRate(rate);
            mapCurrencyRates.put(currencyCode, currencyRate);
          }     
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

I have a wild guess that maybe there is mis-match between version of dependency between heroku environment and my localhost
here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>vn.techmaster</groupId>
    <artifactId>money</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>money</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any suggestion how I can fix this error on Heroku. Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that there is a problem with reading the resources as files because on Heroku, they are inside of the jar and locally you are probably not running from the jar file. Check the log files on Heroku if you see a problem. You can also try to read the files as streams like this `InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I've checked the log and so far there is no problem informed. But as I spend nearly whole day try to solve this problem base on your suggested theory. I firgure out how to solve this bug. And man, happily, code run well now on heroku. I want to say: thank you!

Comment: btw I dont know how to like your cmt, or  how to up your reputation

Comment: I have added an answer now that you should be able to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not read resources as files because when they are packed inside a jar file (like is the case when running on Heroku) this will no longer work.

As an alternative, read the files as a stream:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)
```